# Applying for US tourist visa from UK

Tags: visas, usa, uk, indian-citizens, tourist-visas

I am an Indian passport holder residing in UK under Tier 2 ITC visa. I plan to visit Orlando (USA) with my wife for a week and return back to London.

Is it possible for me to apply from London and what are the requirements and chances of getting tourist visa to USA?

Is there any 90 day visa rule after returning? because our visa extension is likely to happen during August for it's expiring on 15th Sept 2015 and our travel plan is just for a week from 25th June to 1st July.

Comment: Did you check here ? http://london.usembassy.gov/niv/apply.html

Comment: For US nonimmigrant visas you can apply at any embassy in the world (with only a few rare exceptions). It's only immigrant visas that require you to apply from your home country.

Answer (score 6):

You can apply for a US visa in any country in which you are present, but you are recommended to apply in the country where you are residing. Since you are residing in the UK, that is already the best place to apply.